# Minecraft server on VPS crashes due to ressource and watchdog error

Tags: linux, memory, java, vps, minecraft

I rent a VPS with 8GB RAM to host a minecraft server for my friends, but the server crashes around once a day. To setup the server i used https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/know-how/minecraft-server-linux/.
Looking into the crash reports there seems to be a problem with the allocation of the ressources. So i tried to look at the java version but i get an similary error.

```
java -version
[0.002s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "GC Thread#0" - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 4k, detached.
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Cannot create worker GC thread. Out of system resources.
```

Looking at the remaining Memory there should be enough RAM.

```
top - 16:57:33 up 21:02,  2 users,  load average: 0,48, 0,29, 0,30
Tasks:  27 total,   1 running,  26 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  5,3 us,  0,5 sy,  0,0 ni, 94,2 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :   8192,0 total,   4797,7 free,   3144,7 used,    249,6 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0,0 total,      0,0 free,      0,0 used.   5047,1 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   7875 root      20   0 6957728   3,0g  30496 S  21,3  37,9  18:44.59 java
      1 root      20   0  165440   9440   6784 S   0,0   0,1   0:02.08 systemd
      2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 kthreadd/300570
      3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 khelper
     62 root      20   0   47660  17000  16000 S   0,0   0,2   0:07.26 systemd-journal
    132 root      20   0   21416   4568   3608 S   0,0   0,1   0:00.11 systemd-udevd
    175 root      20   0    6876   2636   2384 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.09 cron
    176 message+  20   0    8208   3412   2840 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.05 dbus-daemon
    182 syslog    20   0  152404   3844   3360 S   0,0   0,0   0:01.15 rsyslogd
    185 root      20   0   14888   4828   4016 S   0,0   0,1   0:00.14 systemd-logind
    237 systemd+  20   0   16104   4832   3944 S   0,0   0,1   0:00.73 systemd-network
    302 root      20   0   15408   9340   7700 S   0,0   0,1   0:02.16 sshd
    309 root      20   0    5780    716    624 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 agetty
    310 root      20   0    2800   1056    968 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 agetty
    353 root      20   0   20520   4308   1964 S   0,0   0,1   0:01.61 sendmail-mta
    355 root      20   0    9668   2384   2048 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 xinetd
    407 systemd+  20   0   25252  11928   7888 S   0,0   0,1   0:00.44 systemd-resolve
    522 root      20   0    7296   2656   1980 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.01 screen
    523 root      20   0    7616   3860   3228 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 bash
   7843 root      20   0   16156  10168   8104 S   0,0   0,1   0:00.18 sshd
   7854 root      20   0    7720   4392   3748 S   0,0   0,1   0:00.02 bash
   7873 root      20   0   10236   4892   4368 S   0,0   0,1   0:00.00 sudo
   7874 root      20   0   10236    572      0 S   0,0   0,0   0:00.00 sudo
   8480 root      20   0   15408   8700   7152 S   0,0   0,1   0:00.00 sshd
   8483 root      20   0   15408   8948   7400 S   0,0   0,1   0:00.00 sshd
   8484 root      20   0   10296   3780   3188 R   0,0   0,0   0:00.02 top
   8485 root      20   0   15408   8920   7368 S   0,0   0,1   0:00.00 sshd
```

The crash report logs

LOG 1

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// You should try our sister game, Minceraft!

Time: 2023-03-24 01:43:45
Description: Exception in server tick loop

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:802)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:945)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1364)
        at bcr.i(SourceFile:131)
        at bcr.a(SourceFile:124)
        at bcq.c(SourceFile:31)
        at deq.a(SourceFile:234)
        at deq.a(SourceFile:172)
        at dep.a(SourceFile:116)
        at dfs.a(SourceFile:300)
        at dfs.f(SourceFile:381)
        at it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.longs.LongOpenHashSet.forEach(LongOpenHashSet.java:756)
        at dfs.b(SourceFile:375)
        at aip.a(SourceFile:777)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:540)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.b(SourceFile:564)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:838)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(SourceFile:675)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:266)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
        Minecraft Version: 1.19.4
        Minecraft Version ID: 1.19.4
        Operating System: Linux (amd64) version 5.2.0
        Java Version: 17.0.6, Private Build
        Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode, sharing), Private Build
        Memory: 1995933808 bytes (1903 MiB) / 2524971008 bytes (2408 MiB) up to 6442450944 bytes (6144 MiB)
        CPUs: 4
        Processor Vendor: AuthenticAMD
        Processor Name: AMD EPYC 7452 32-Core Processor
        Identifier: AuthenticAMD Family 23 Model 49 Stepping 0
        Microarchitecture: Zen 2
        Frequency (GHz): -0.00
        Number of physical packages: 1
        Number of physical CPUs: 1
        Number of logical CPUs: 1
        Graphics card #0 name: unknown
        Graphics card #0 vendor: unknown
        Graphics card #0 VRAM (MB): 0.00
        Graphics card #0 deviceId: unknown
        Graphics card #0 versionInfo: unknown
        Virtual memory max (MB): 0.00
        Virtual memory used (MB): 2966.25
        Swap memory total (MB): 0.00
        Swap memory used (MB): 0.00
        JVM Flags: 2 total; -Xms2G -Xmx6G
        Server Running: true
        Player Count: 0 / 20; []
        Data Packs: vanilla
        Enabled Feature Flags: minecraft:vanilla
        World Generation: Stable
        Is Modded: Probably not. Server jar signature and brand is untouched
        Type: Dedicated Server (map_server.txt)
```

LOG 2

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Sorry :(

Time: 2023-03-25 17:38:57
Description: Watching Server

java.lang.Error: Watchdog
        at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
        at bco.bs(SourceFile:151)
        at bco.c(SourceFile:141)
        at ain.a(SourceFile:140)
        at cmi.a(SourceFile:206)
        at cml.a(SourceFile:161)
        at cmi.d(SourceFile:200)
        at cmi.l(SourceFile:195)
        at cmi.b_(SourceFile:387)
        at bfh.o(SourceFile:1287)
        at bfh.ao(SourceFile:499)
        at bfx.ao(SourceFile:348)
        at bfh.l(SourceFile:469)
        at bfx.l(SourceFile:2361)
        at bym.l(SourceFile:282)
        at aiq.m(SourceFile:509)
        at aji.c(SourceFile:268)
        at sq.a(SourceFile:254)
        at ajh.c(SourceFile:172)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.b(SourceFile:912)
        at ahq.b(SourceFile:283)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:828)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(SourceFile:675)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:266)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer$$Lambda$4485/0x00000008014a9d58.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Server Watchdog
Stacktrace:
        at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
        at bco.bs(SourceFile:151)
        at bco.c(SourceFile:141)
        at ain.a(SourceFile:140)
        at cmi.a(SourceFile:206)
        at cml.a(SourceFile:161)
        at cmi.d(SourceFile:200)
        at cmi.l(SourceFile:195)
        at cmi.b_(SourceFile:387)
        at bfh.o(SourceFile:1287)
        at bfh.ao(SourceFile:499)
        at bfx.ao(SourceFile:348)
        at bfh.l(SourceFile:469)
        at bfx.l(SourceFile:2361)
        at bym.l(SourceFile:282)
        at aiq.m(SourceFile:509)
        at aji.c(SourceFile:268)
        at sq.a(SourceFile:254)
        at ajh.c(SourceFile:172)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.b(SourceFile:912)
        at ahq.b(SourceFile:283)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:828)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(SourceFile:675)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:266)

-- Thread Dump --
Details:
        Threads: "Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 Id=2 RUNNABLE
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(Native Method)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(Reference.java:253)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:215)


"Finalizer" daemon prio=8 Id=3 WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@28c78967
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        -  waiting on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@28c78967
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:176)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:172)


"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=9 Id=4 RUNNABLE


"Notification Thread" daemon prio=9 Id=11 RUNNABLE


"Common-Cleaner" daemon prio=8 Id=12 TIMED_WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@5ea69bed
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        -  waiting on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@5ea69bed
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
        at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.run(CleanerImpl.java:140)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(InnocuousThread.java:162)


"DestroyJavaVM" prio=5 Id=14 RUNNABLE


"JNA Cleaner" daemon prio=5 Id=18 WAITING on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@e0d8630
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        -  waiting on java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock@e0d8630
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:155)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:176)
        at com.sun.jna.internal.Cleaner$1.run(Cleaner.java:58)


"Timer hack thread" daemon prio=5 Id=19 TIMED_WAITING
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
        at ac$9.run(SourceFile:822)


"Server thread" prio=5 Id=23 TIMED_WAITING on java.lang.String@35cfcd8
        at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        -  waiting on java.lang.String@35cfcd8
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
        at bco.bs(SourceFile:151)
        at bco.c(SourceFile:141)
        at ain.a(SourceFile:140)
        at cmi.a(SourceFile:206)
        at cml.a(SourceFile:161)
        at cmi.d(SourceFile:200)
        ...


"Server console handler" daemon prio=5 Id=25 RUNNABLE (in native)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:276)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:282)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:343)
        -  locked java.io.BufferedInputStream@69cf66ad
        at java.base@17.0.6/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:270)
        at java.base@17.0.6/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:313)
        at java.base@17.0.6/sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:188)
        -  locked java.io.InputStreamReader@b9151a2
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:177)
        ...


"Netty Epoll Server IO #0" daemon prio=5 Id=26 RUNNABLE (in native)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


"Server Watchdog" daemon prio=5 Id=34 RUNNABLE
        at java.management@17.0.6/sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpThreads0(Native Method)
        at java.management@17.0.6/sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpAllThreads(ThreadImpl.java:521)
        at java.management@17.0.6/sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpAllThreads(ThreadImpl.java:509)
        at aht.run(SourceFile:47)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


"Netty Epoll Server IO #1" daemon prio=5 Id=35 RUNNABLE (in native)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


"Netty Epoll Server IO #2" daemon prio=5 Id=39 RUNNABLE (in native)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


"Netty Epoll Server IO #3" daemon prio=5 Id=40 RUNNABLE (in native)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native Method)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:209)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.epollWait(Native.java:202)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.epollWaitNoTimerChange(EpollEventLoop.java:306)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:363)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


"Netty Epoll Server IO #4" daemon prio=5 Id=44 BLOCKED on java.util.Collections$SynchronizedRandomAccessList@10e688e0 owned by "Server thread" Id=23
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:2104)
        -  blocked on java.util.Collections$SynchronizedRandomAccessList@10e688e0
        at ajh$1.initChannel(SourceFile:101)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.initChannel(ChannelInitializer.java:129)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.handlerAdded(ChannelInitializer.java:112)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.callHandlerAdded(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:938)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:609)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.access$100(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:46)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$PendingHandlerAddedTask.execute(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1463)
        ...


"Netty Epoll Server IO #5" daemon prio=5 Id=45 BLOCKED on java.util.Collections$SynchronizedRandomAccessList@10e688e0 owned by "Server thread" Id=23
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:2104)
        -  blocked on java.util.Collections$SynchronizedRandomAccessList@10e688e0
        at ajh$1.initChannel(SourceFile:101)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.initChannel(ChannelInitializer.java:129)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.handlerAdded(ChannelInitializer.java:112)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.callHandlerAdded(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:938)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:609)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.access$100(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:46)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$PendingHandlerAddedTask.execute(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1463)
        ...


"Netty Epoll Server IO #6" daemon prio=5 Id=78 BLOCKED on java.util.Collections$SynchronizedRandomAccessList@10e688e0 owned by "Server thread" Id=23
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:2104)
        -  blocked on java.util.Collections$SynchronizedRandomAccessList@10e688e0
        at ajh$1.initChannel(SourceFile:101)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.initChannel(ChannelInitializer.java:129)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.handlerAdded(ChannelInitializer.java:112)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.callHandlerAdded(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:938)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:609)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.access$100(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:46)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$PendingHandlerAddedTask.execute(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1463)
        ...


"Netty Epoll Server IO #7" daemon prio=5 Id=100 BLOCKED on java.util.Collections$SynchronizedRandomAccessList@10e688e0 owned by "Server thread" Id=23
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.Collections$SynchronizedCollection.add(Collections.java:2104)
        -  blocked on java.util.Collections$SynchronizedRandomAccessList@10e688e0
        at ajh$1.initChannel(SourceFile:101)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.initChannel(ChannelInitializer.java:129)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer.handlerAdded(ChannelInitializer.java:112)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.callHandlerAdded(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:938)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerAdded0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:609)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.access$100(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:46)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$PendingHandlerAddedTask.execute(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1463)
        ...


"Worker-Main-828" daemon prio=5 Id=914 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@2f1479b8
        at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@2f1479b8
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkUntil(LockSupport.java:410)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.awaitWork(ForkJoinPool.java:1726)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1623)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)


"Worker-Main-829" daemon prio=5 Id=915 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@2f1479b8
        at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@2f1479b8
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkUntil(LockSupport.java:410)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.awaitWork(ForkJoinPool.java:1726)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1623)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)


"Worker-Main-830" daemon prio=5 Id=916 TIMED_WAITING on java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@2f1479b8
        at java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool@2f1479b8
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkUntil(LockSupport.java:410)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.awaitWork(ForkJoinPool.java:1726)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1623)
        at java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)



Stacktrace:
        at aht.run(SourceFile:63)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

-- Performance stats --
Details:
        Random tick rate: 3
        Level stats: ResourceKey[minecraft:dimension / minecraft:overworld]: players: 1, entities: 171,171,81,627,529,0,98 [minecraft:chicken:58,minecraft:pig:31,minecraft:sheep:30,minecraft:item:27,minecraft:chest_minecart:12], block_entities: 174 [minecraft:mob_spawner:97,minecraft:sculk_sensor:42,minecraft:sculk_catalyst:14,minecraft:beehive:9,minecraft:furnace:8], block_ticks: 3776, fluid_ticks: 740, chunk_source: Chunks[S] W: 4232 E: 171,171,81,627,529,0,98,
ResourceKey[minecraft:dimension / minecraft:the_nether]: players: 0, entities: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 [], block_entities: 0 [], block_ticks: 0, fluid_ticks: 0, chunk_source: Chunks[S] W: 0 E: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
ResourceKey[minecraft:dimension / minecraft:the_end]: players: 0, entities: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0 [], block_entities: 0 [], block_ticks: 0, fluid_ticks: 0, chunk_source: Chunks[S] W: 0 E: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0

-- System Details --
Details:
        Minecraft Version: 1.19.4
        Minecraft Version ID: 1.19.4
        Operating System: Linux (amd64) version 5.2.0
        Java Version: 17.0.6, Private Build
        Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode, sharing), Private Build
        Memory: 1410956296 bytes (1345 MiB) / 4886364160 bytes (4660 MiB) up to 5368709120 bytes (5120 MiB)
        CPUs: 4
        Processor Vendor: AuthenticAMD
        Processor Name: AMD EPYC 7452 32-Core Processor
        Identifier: AuthenticAMD Family 23 Model 49 Stepping 0
        Microarchitecture: Zen 2
        Frequency (GHz): -0.00
        Number of physical packages: 1
        Number of physical CPUs: 1
        Number of logical CPUs: 1
        Graphics card #0 name: unknown
        Graphics card #0 vendor: unknown
        Graphics card #0 VRAM (MB): 0.00
        Graphics card #0 deviceId: unknown
        Graphics card #0 versionInfo: unknown
        Virtual memory max (MB): 0.00
        Virtual memory used (MB): 5438.89
        Swap memory total (MB): 0.00
        Swap memory used (MB): 0.00
        JVM Flags: 2 total; -Xms2G -Xmx5G
        Server Running: true
        Player Count: 1 / 20; [aiq['player'/123456, l='ServerLevel[world]', x=435.97, y=80.00, z=-6130.18]]
        Data Packs: vanilla
        Enabled Feature Flags: minecraft:vanilla
        World Generation: Stable
        Is Modded: Probably not. Server jar signature and brand is untouched
        Type: Dedicated Server (map_server.txt)
```

The crash report logs

LOG 1

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// You should try our sister game, Minceraft!

Time: 2023-03-24 01:43:45
Description: Exception in server tick loop

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:802)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:945)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1364)
        at bcr.i(SourceFile:131)
        at bcr.a(SourceFile:124)
        at bcq.c(SourceFile:31)
        at deq.a(SourceFile:234)
        at deq.a(SourceFile:172)
        at dep.a(SourceFile:116)
        at dfs.a(SourceFile:300)
        at dfs.f(SourceFile:381)
        at it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.longs.LongOpenHashSet.forEach(LongOpenHashSet.java:756)
        at dfs.b(SourceFile:375)
        at aip.a(SourceFile:777)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:540)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.b(SourceFile:564)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:838)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.w(SourceFile:675)
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:266)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- System Details --
Details:
        Minecraft Version: 1.19.4
        Minecraft Version ID: 1.19.4
        Operating System: Linux (amd64) version 5.2.0
        Java Version: 17.0.6, Private Build
        Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode, sharing), Private Build
        Memory: 1995933808 bytes (1903 MiB) / 2524971008 bytes (2408 MiB) up to 6442450944 bytes (6144 MiB)
        CPUs: 4
        Processor Vendor: AuthenticAMD
        Processor Name: AMD EPYC 7452 32-Core Processor
        Identifier: AuthenticAMD Family 23 Model 49 Stepping 0
        Microarchitecture: Zen 2
        Frequency (GHz): -0.00
        Number of physical packages: 1
        Number of physical CPUs: 1
        Number of logical CPUs: 1
        Graphics card #0 name: unknown
        Graphics card #0 vendor: unknown
        Graphics card #0 VRAM (MB): 0.00
        Graphics card #0 deviceId: unknown
        Graphics card #0 versionInfo: unknown
        Virtual memory max (MB): 0.00
        Virtual memory used (MB): 2966.25
        Swap memory total (MB): 0.00
        Swap memory used (MB): 0.00
        JVM Flags: 2 total; -Xms2G -Xmx6G
        Server Running: true
        Player Count: 0 / 20; []
        Data Packs: vanilla
        Enabled Feature Flags: minecraft:vanilla
        World Generation: Stable
        Is Modded: Probably not. Server jar signature and brand is untouched
        Type: Dedicated Server (map_server.txt)
```

Comment: Memory management in Java is controlled by lots of command-line flags and options. There should be guides about that on the net.

Comment: **You need to allocate more memory to the Java VM.**

Comment: @Ramhound how can i do this?

Comment: @BigKeF - Use larger values here: `-Xms2G -Xmx6G` but that only works if your server has more system memory.

Comment: @Ramhound - My VPS has 8GBs of Memory. How much would you recommend, when its only purpose is to run the server?

Comment: @BigKeF - The minimum amount will be whatever the Java VM requires to run the Minecraft server.  It appears crashes are memory related to the Java VM. I mean, "possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached", seems pretty clear you need to allow the Java VM to allocate a larger heap. I have no specific recommendations since I know absolutely nothing about the Minecraft world you are trying to load or the Minecraft server configuration. Has your research indicated, that 8 GB with only 6 GB allocated to the Java VM, is enough to run your Minecraft server?

Comment: @Ramhound - I tried to start the Server with 6GB max, but it still crashed due to a OutOfMemory Error. We are at max 4 ppl online on a vanilla server so 6GB should be enough. After researching how much RAM an MC server needs, I found out that 2GB should be enough for my Server.

Comment: @BigKeF - It’s not. Increase -Xms2G to 4G

Comment: @Ramhound - https://apexminecrafthosting.com/how-much-ram-do-i-need-for-my-server/ the tabel on this website says that 2GB would be enough for my usage.

Comment: The website is wrong. Your crash logs prove that is the case. I can’t help you at this point since your not willing to try configuration changes.

Comment: @Ramhound - In log 1 it says at the bottom that 3000MB of Virtual Memory are used, but 6GB are the max it can use.

Comment: @BigKeF - I will be unable to help you.